# how to use JPA in a worker thread?

Tags: jpa, weblogic, java-ee-5

I'm using WebLogic 10.3.5.0 with JPA 2.0 and have the following scenario:

- user needs to start a task takes some time to complete;
- this task needs to read and write to DB;

One solution would be to write a worker and use the WorkManager feature to start this from an session EJB.

How should I use JPA from this worker to access the DB in a transactional manner?

Comment: Make the worker thread call EJB methods?